# what is the meaning of "[dir]" with html css

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

Please explain me what is the meaning of "[dir]" in following css:

```
[dir] .layoutContainer {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(57,76,96,.15);
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does the HTML look like? That looks like it's trying to select a `.layoutContainer` element that's a child of an element with a `dir` attribute, but without context it's a guess.

Comment: I don't think it has any meaning at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a attribute. Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        [dir]{
            background-color: red;
        }

        [dir] .layoutContainer {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div dir='aa'>A<span class='layoutContainer'>B</span>C</div>
    <div dir='aa'>A</div>
    <div dir='aa'>A</div>

    <br>

    <b dir='bb'>Bo<span class='layoutContainer'>l</span>d</b>

    <br>

    <h1 dir>He<span class='layoutContainer'>ad</span>ing</h1>

    <h2>He<span class='layoutContainer'>ad</span>ing 2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside CSS, using `[dir]`, we selecting all elements having `dir` attribute no matter if the attribute has has any value or if it is stand-alone.

Here and inside your code, `[dir] .layoutContainer` selecting all elements of class `layoutContainer` which are children of all those elements which contains `dir` attribute.